# ¿Cómo guardar datos de una API json con PHP y Mysql cada 1 minuto?

Tags: php, mysql, json, cron

Tengo acceso a una API que me devuelve datos en json. Quiero guardarlos en mi base de datos para crear historial. Ejemplo de json:

```
"datos": {
    "euro/dolar": "1,43432"
}
```

El valor de 'euro/dolar' cambia cada minuto. En este momento tengo mi variable PHP:

```
$dato_de_forex['eurodolar'];
```

¿Como puedo guardarlo automáticamente cada minuto en mi tabla Mysql sin que nadie tenga que visitar mi página para ejecutar el PHP?

El servido que utilizo es Apache2 con Linux.

Gracias!

Comment: que api estas utilizando para la información de Divisas?

Comment: Gracias Carlos por tu pregunta. No utilizo api para información sobre divisas. Era solo un ejemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer un mini-daemon con do while y sleep() e insertarlo en /etc/rc.local para que se ejecute en forma automática, así evitas el problema de cron que se sobrecargue cada 1 minuto, no olvides agregar tú código para extraer $dato_de_forex['eurodolar'].

```
/usr/src/euro.php

<?php
$bucle=true;
do {
$euro=$dato_de_forex['eurodolar'];
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","mi_usuario","mi_contraseña","mi_bd");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "update table_euro set euro=$euro where id=1")
mysqi_close($link);
sleep(60);//1 minuto
} while ($bucle);
?>
```

Luego en /etc/rc.local agregas la línea

```
php -q usr/src/euro.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar ejecutar un archivo php mediante CRON en tu servidor.

Como implementarlo dependerá del tipo de servidor que tengas, pero haciendo una pequeña búsqueda en google deberías encontrar una solución para tu servidor. Por ejemplo he hecho una búsqueda rápida y he encontrado un pequeño tutorial de como hacerlo en Linux https://voragine.net/weblogs/como-ejecutar-php-periodicamente-con-cron-en-un-servidor-linux

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta